# Can I seed data on required property in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it recommended to seed data with `[Required]` property?

To be more specific let us take this example

```
public class Equipment : BaseEntity
    {
        #region Properties
        public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EquipmentName { get; set; }
        public EquipmentType EquipmentType { get; set; }
        #region Navigation Properties
        public ICollection<EventEquipment> EventEquipments { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public Equipment()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        #endregion
    }
}
```

can I use `EquipmentName` property to seed data? Is this the recommended approach?
If not, what is the best property to use to seed data?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're going to seed data you don't have any option but to provide values for required properties. Or are you actually asking how to set default values, which is not the same as seeding?

Comment: ok if I want to seed some data using this class how would you do that ... give an example .....the essence of my question "how People Professionals do that "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna seed data, better way is to seed whole objects, not only single property. On the other hand, there's no formal restriction to seed required property.